# How to enable fuzzy search on solr 7.7?

Tags: solr

I am trying to fuzzy seach on a title text, but solr does not give me any results on a misspelled brand name "*hilfinger*" query:

```
http://rex:8983/solr/project/select?fq=white_label_id%3A6&q=title%3Ahilfinger~
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"title:hilfinger~",
      "fq":"white_label_id:6",
      "_":"1554887612686"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Using standard search I will get results on correct naming *hilfiger*:

```
http://rex:8983/solr/project/select?fq=white_label_id%3A6&q=title%3Ahilfiger
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"title:hilfiger",
      "fq":"white_label_id:6",
      "_":"1554887612686"}},
  "response":{"numFound":27,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
```

Is there something I need to activate in the configuration of solr to enable fuzzy search, or what is the reason for getting 0 results?

Comment: What is the type of the field `title`? Stemming might affect the stored token, meaning that hilfiger is stemmed to hilfig, and that's further off from hilfinger than the default edit distance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can. You just have to properly configure the fields in the `schema.xml` you wish to enable fuzzy search or partial matches on. You can add filters to the desired field during index time to tell Solr to store the [`ngrams`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) of each value as well in addition to the original value. Later on, fuzzy search can be performed on this field. Two types of such filters exist by default and you only have to attach them to your index analyzer chain of filters.

- [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter) - only match prefixes and suffixes (match only edges of a search phrase)
- [NGramFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter)     - match ngrams from anywhere in the phrase

In both cases, you will have to define a minimum and a maximum size of the ngrams to generate during index time. (Take note that this will increase the size of your index as well.) Let's define your title field in the schema.xml with a filter.

```
<fieldType name="title" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here the configuration defines minimum size of the ngrams to be 2 letters and maximum to be 15.
You can alter the filter to enable partial matching from anywhere of the field value by replacing the line,

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
```

with,

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
```